# Linux Daemon - runs functions twice

Tags: c++, linux, daemon

My Libmongoose based Server runs fine when on Windows in terminal as well as a Service.

Now, I am porting it to Linux. It works perfect when run in the terminal. Now, I wanted to run it as a Daemon - it works but to my surprise it invokes all the functions twice. I checked the PID only one process is running. It's driving me crazy. The daemonizing code is as follows:

```
if(CommandArgs.at("-d") == "true")
{
    #if __linux
    pid_t pid, sid;
    pid = fork();
    if (pid < 0) {
       exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    if (pid > 0) {
       exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
    }
    umask(0);
    sid = setsid();
    if (sid < 0) {
       exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    /* Change the current working directory */
    if ((chdir("/")) < 0) {
       exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    /* Close out the standard file descriptors */
    close(STDIN_FILENO);
    close(STDOUT_FILENO);
    close(STDERR_FILENO);
    if(start_server() == false)
    {
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    else
    {
        signal(SIGHUP, signal_handler);
        signal(SIGTERM, signal_handler);
        signal(SIGINT, signal_handler);
        signal(SIGQUIT, signal_handler);
        pause();
    }
    //exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
    return 0;
    #endif
}
```

Now, after i invoke the `start_server()` function -functions inside are invoked twice:

```
static bool start_server()
{
    try{
        // invoked once as expected
        MyLogger(2, "Info: Starting  Server ...");  

        #ifdef _WIN32
        mutex = CreateMutex( NULL, FALSE, NULL); 
        #else
        pthread_mutex_init(&mutex, NULL);  
                #endif

        for(int i = 0; i < serverConf.totalThreads; i++)
        {       
                        server[i] = mg_create_server(NULL, event_handler);
            if(i==0)
            {
                const char * error_msg = mg_set_option(server[0], "listening_port", serverConf.port.c_str());
                 if (error_msg != NULL) {
                    MyLogger(1,"Error: Cannot bind to the port:",serverConf.port.c_str());
                    return false;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                mg_copy_listeners(server[0], server[i]);
                        }
        }
        // Now all the logging happening twice
        ServerStarted = true;
        for(int i = 0; i < serverConf.totalThreads; i++)
        {
            mg_start_thread(serve, server[i]);
        }
        // server1 goes to separate thread, server 2 runs in main thread.
        // IMPORTANT: NEVER LET DIFFERENT THREADS HANDLE THE SAME SERVER.

        MyLogger(2, "Info: Server Started!");  // why was i logged twice
        MyLogger(2, "Info: Listening on port:",  mg_get_option(server[0], "listening_port")); // why was i logged twice

    }
    catch(std::exception& e)
    {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Now the logs are:

2015-04-27, 23:06:39 Info: Starting Server..

2015-04-27, 23:06:41 Info: Server Started!

2015-04-27, 23:06:41 Info: Server Started!

2015-04-27, 23:06:41 Info: Listening on port: 8091

2015-04-27, 23:06:41 Info: Listening on port: 8091

```
void MyLogger(int level, const char* msg1)
{
    if(level > LogLevel)
    {
        return;
    }
    string time = currentDateTime();
    std::ofstream out(LogFilePath.c_str(), std::fstream::app);
        if(silentMode == false)
    {
         cout<<"\n"<<time<<" "<<msg1<<"\n";
    }
    out<<"\n"<<time<<" "<<msg1<<"\n";

}
```

Comment: ;Never compare == true;  because 'true' could be most any value, other than 0  Instead compare != false  or even better: 'if( CommandArgs.at("-d") )'

Comment: Where is the minimal example that you should be familiar with?

Comment: when writing code, always use spaces for indentation, not tabs  The posted code clearly shows why tabs should never be used for indenting.

Comment: the code is clearly C++, so suggest removing the 'c' tag

Comment: @Kenny Added the logger code

Comment: Are you *sure* that code matches what you're actually running, and that it presents the code path by which the log output you present is generated?  My first guess would have been that after `fork()`ing, you allow both parent and child process to proceed to `start_server()`, but that's not consistent with your code.  Is it possible that you have already forked once before reaching your code handling argument `-d`?  It might be illuminating to log the process IDs along with the messages.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I already mentioned that in the answer, I tried logging in mylogger() getpid(), the logger showed the same pid. Double log entries are shown only after the first for loop in start_server function

Comment: You don't show the "Starting Server.." message being duplicated like the others.  Is that an accurate representation of the ouput?

Comment: @JohnBollinger Yes, it is correct.  - it starts double logging after the first forl oop in start_server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems likely that the messages are being duplicated by function `MyLogger()`.  In the event that `silentMode == false`, it will print the same message to two streams, but they may in fact be *the same* stream, or else the output from both may end up redirected to the same place.

That could start happening where you say it does if one of the functions
`mg_create_server()`, `mg_set_option()`, or `mg_copy_listeners()` modifies `out`, sets `silentMode` to `false`, or otherwise makes a change that would produce such a result.

Comment: You are right commenting cout fixed the issue. Thanks a ton!